# What is a word for a person who is easily amazed?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for a person who is amazed at everything, no matter how big or small? (Either an adjective or a noun would be fine)

Comment: We usually say "easily impressed".

Comment: **credulous** *adjective*: having or showing too great a readiness to believe things; synonyms: gullible, naive, too trusting, easily taken in, *impressionable*.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for **impressionable**.

Per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impressionable):

> **impressionable**
>
> adjective im·pres·sion·able \im-ˈpre-sh(ə-)nə-bəl\ : easy to influence
>
> Examples of IMPRESSIONABLE
>
> - The teacher was accused of forcing his political beliefs on impressionable teenagers.
> - The book had a profound effect on his impressionable young mind.